# How can I refer to a MKMapView in UITests?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uitest

I've tried different strategies to get a reference to a `MKMapView` in my UITests, but it can't be found.

For example:

```
app.maps.firstMatch.exists
```

Or using `accessibilityIdentifier`:

```
app.maps["MyMap"].exists

app.otherElements["MyMap"].exists
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your UI like? Could you please show all the relevant code or the Storyboard?

Comment: My UI is a simple view controller with a MKMapView as subview. It has all be added in a storyboard.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. This code works for me just fine `let app = XCUIApplication(); let map = app.maps.firstMatch; print(map.exists)`

Comment: @ielyamani ok thanks for the confirm. The issue must be somewhere else then...

Comment: @aneuryzm Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour in my app, simple ViewController with an MKMapView subview.